# String representation

Tags: php, string, explode

Can anyone tell me why is this

```
$pole = explode("\n", file_get_contents('obce.txt'));

echo $pole[1];  //in obce.txt it is Test
```

different from

```
$pole[1]="Test";
echo $pole[1];
```

For me, it seem to be the same thing.

Comment: [Wut ?](http://www.memecreator.org/static/images/memes/459010.jpg) In the first snippet you're reading from a file and getting the second line while in the second snippet you're actualy creating a variable with index "1" and giving it the value "Test".

Comment: be more clear, which is the problem?

Comment: when i print this as js code one is string but from text file is is something else

Comment: -1 hard to understand the actual question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in Windows the end of line caracters is "\r\n".

Try:

```
$pole = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents('obce.txt'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `obce.txt` has just one string `Test` in first line. If that is the case then when you read the file and explode there will be just one element in array `pole` and to print it you need to do:

```
echo $pole[0];
```